How can I apply probability to score better at entrance tests? (real-life situation)
Context:
I am a doctor from India. Over the course of the next year I will be preparing for a post-graduation exam called INICET. In India, limited PG seats make exams highly competitive, with minimal differences in scores among top-ranking aspirants, especially within the top 100.
This is the format of INICET:



Feature
Details




Duration
3 hours


Number of Questions
200


Type of Questions
MCQs - 1 question, 4 options, 1 correct answer


Correct Answer
One Mark (+1)


Incorrect Answer
Minus one-third (-1/3)


Unanswered/Marked for Review
0



The 200 questions are divided into four parts, each containing 50 questions with a 45-minute time limit. Candidates can only view and answer questions in the active part, and once the 45-minute limit expires, the part is automatically submitted(no more changes allowed), and the next part is activated sequentially. Only the questions in that active section can be accessed.
In case of a tie in the score, ranks are determined first by (the one with) fewer negative marks and after that they prefer those that are older by age.
They rank students by the percentile of their scores. To get an idea of the competitiveness, you can check out the rank list here- List of the qualified candidate in INI-CET July 2024 session.
The Problem Statement:
In order for me to get into my desired college(which is AIIMS Delhi; the best one in the country) and my desired specialization, I would require to get a national rank below 250-300, in an exam where 60,000+ students participate.
Assuming that I will have to achieve this goal in the next 2 exam sessions only(the exam is conducted semi-annually), what is the number of guesses I must make in an exam to increase my chances of success?
The thing is a lot of people here attempt 190+ out of 200 questions even if they don't know anything about many of the questions (blind guesses), which I believe they do because if one attempts 190 questions they have a chance to score 190(however slim it may be) as opposed to attempting only say 140 questions.
Let's say I divide the questions into:

Sure questions: Topics I have read well, and can make a good educated guess out of if needed
Guess questions: Topics I have no clue about or just very in-depth topics from areas I have covered but not to that extent

Is there a fixed limit of questions I must attempt in total or guess in total? Or should I keep a constant ratio between the two? How would I go about doing this during the exam? What should I do if I can eliminate 1/2 of the incorrect options for a question?
Or perhaps I am approaching this in an entirely wrong way?
My Understanding So Far:
Since each question has 4 possible answers(1 correct and 3 wrong), there is 25% chance of answering correct and 75% percent chance of answering wrong if a blind guess is being made. So, for say n guesses you could get:
0.25n * (+1) = +0.25n marks  
0.75n * (-1/3) = -0.25n marks

Giving a net of 0 marks, which means for a very large n, I would be scoring the same whether I guess them all or leave them all unanswered. But since I have only 2 exams left to attempt, this would mean my guessing score could be positive or negative.
I was wondering if someone could help me figure out a logical answer/strategy to this. I am not very good at math, so please explain it in simple terms.
I will prepare whole-heartedly from my side and avoid depending on luck, but I also want to try to improve my chances by leveraging the power of probability.
Thank you so much for your time!

If you know nothing whatsoever about a question, don't answer it.  If you know enough to eliminate (or deem unlikely) even one of the answers, choose what you think is the most-likely answer.

Don't you think you should be studying medical science rather than probability theory?

If you are blind guessing the net is zero, however if you can for sure exclude even one of the answers then you should blind guess one of the last three, because now you will have a positive net. Maybe a good strategy is to not blind guess (since in a case of tie it'll be worse to have negative score, and you are "earning" 0 from doing this), but blind guess every time you can for sure exclude one option.
Good luck for your test :)

The good strategy depends highly on 'how confident you are'. If you are very very confident, if you think that you will be able to answer correctly more than 190 questions, without guessing, the good strategy is to avoid negative points. (so not answer the questions where you are totally ignorant) (it was my 1st opinion, but see EDIT).
But what I understand is that scoring 190 or more is very difficult. So you need to be brillant, and also to be very lucky.
For example, imagine you have 180 questions where you are totally sure to know the answer, 12 questions where you can eliminate 2 answers, and 8 questions where you are totally ignorant. If you decide to not answer those 8 questions, your expected score is only 186, it is not enough. It is possible to reach 190, if you are lucky but the probability is very small (1/315).
In this example, if you answer 'randomly' the 8 questions where you are totally ignorant, you don't improve the expected score, but you increase the variance, so you increase the probability to obtain 190 or more.
EDIT :
In case of Tie, people are ranked based on number of errors.
Ok.
But when we apply this rule to the subset of candidates with a very high score (greater than 180), this rule has no impact.
For example, a score of 189.33 can be obtained with 200 answers (192 correct+8 wrong) or with 196 answers (191+5) or with 192 answers (190+2)
But only the 1st scenario makes sense. It is highly not-probable to be totally ignorant on 4 or 8 questions so to decide to not answer to those questions, and to obtain in the same time 190 and 191 correct answers.
So, to manage the ties, for people with a very high score, we can say that the only rule is based on the age of the student.
So, there is no negative impact to answer randomly if you are totally ignorant for a question. There is a benefit (increase the variance), and only a benefit.
Impact of the age : The strategy should be different if you think you are young compared to other candidates.
We speak about people who will obtain a very high score (more than 185). It is clear than all those people will answer to 200 or 199 or eventually 198 or 197 questions. But mainly 200 or 199.
Imagine I am younger than other candidates. Imagine I know the answer for 185 or 186 questions, and I have big doubts for the rest. I need to be lucky to obtain a score of 190 or more.
I can answer to 200 questions, I have a small probability $P_1$ to obtain a score 190.67, and I will be the last one in this group, because I am younger than other candidates.
I can answer to 199 questions, I have a small probability $P_2$ to obtain a score 189.67, and I will be the last one in this group, because I am younger than other candidates.
Or I can answer to 198 questions , I have a small probability $P_3$ to obtain a score 190, and I will be the only one with this score, because very few brillant students will answer to only 198 questions.
Nobody should have a score 190.33, because you need to skip 3 or 7 questions to obtain a score 190.33, and it is highly improbable.
If $P_3$ is greater than $P_1$ (and it is), and if you are younger than other candidates, this strategy may be good.
Edit :

I have edited, to switch Young / Old
In this reflexion about age of the candidate, I consider that 1st criteria is number of wrong answers, and 2nd criteria is age. But we can be pretty sure that if many people have a very big score (like 190 for example), they all have same number of correct answers, and same number of wrong answers. It would be very strange to have 190 correct answers, and 0 wrong answer, or even 191 correct answers, and 3 wrong answers. I deliberatly ignore those cases, which impact is very low.


Hi, thank you so much for your time. I am sorry I wasn't clear. Older age is preferred over younger age, if even the negative marks have tied up.(I have edited this part in the post)
Also I don't think I am older than most candidates. So my strategy will have to depend mostly on how many guesses to attempt right?I don't think  I would have to worry about the age then.
